# Having trouble with a half hot switch

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch, receptacle

I am currently going through the process of replacing all the outdated cream colored outlets in my home with white ones. Recently I was doing the ones in the master bedroom, where there is no overhead light, and instead there are wall hung lamps attached to a half hot outlet controlled by the light switch. As I was replacing these I didn't think to make sure that the new one was wired any special way, and did it the way I believe the old one was set up. However, now the new outlet is not working off of the switch, it is acting just as any other outlet with both receptacles being hot, but not controlled by the switch. At first I did remember that I hadn't broken the gold tab on the outlet so I figured there's my problem. I went back and did that and still no dice, the light switch doesn't control the outlet, and I am at a loss of what to do. Here are some pictures of what I am working with:

Inside of switch box:

[image: Inside of switch box]

Right side of outlet:

[image: Right side of outlet]

Left side:

[image: Left side]

I've had the red wire on both top and bottom of the right side and it didn't seem to make a difference. Thank you so much for all of your help!

I am just about positive that the switch and outlet are wired properly, but it's not working. The outlet has two white, two black, a red, and a ground, which also confused me a bit since most others didn't have as many wires coming through to it. I apologize if this is a dumb question and the solution is something blatantly obvious, but I appreciate all the info and help you can provide!!

Comment: What color are the wires at the light switch, and which tabs are broken off on the old outlet?

Comment: I uploaded the images for you. The wiring looks basically correct to me, but hopefully one of the experts can figure it out. The basic setup should be black from panel to switch, red from switch to outlet, whites nutted together in the switch box for future use, white to top & bottom of outlet (technically only need one since they are connected anyway; so second is a convenience to chain to the next outlet), red to switched outlet, black to unswitched outlet (and extra black is there too to chain to next outlet along with one of the neutral whites). So it all looks good except that

Comment: Light switch has one black, one red, and a ground.The broken tab is the bronze/black side

Comment: the 2 blacks to the outlet should be done with a pigtail so that only one wire is on the screw to make a better connection - but that wouldn't explain the problem you're having.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. Well-stated question, especially after @manassehkatz uploaded your pictures. Keep 'em coming!

Comment: Thank you for the help uploading the pictures!

Comment: Did you replace outlets elsewhere in the room? Did any of those also have red wires? I think you mixed something up in one of those outlets.

Comment: @longneck, I replaced all of them in the room and I can't say for sure whether or not they had red wires but it's totally possible. What should those look like if they did have a red wire?


The black wire on the receptacle that looks like it is barely on there is actually fully on the screw, its just a poor angle and a strange bend to the wire, however it could probably still stand to be re-seated on there

Comment: Not regarding the question but you might want to reterminate some of these ... that connection on the one white wire on the receptacle, only half a hook and insulation under the screw, and the one black is hanging by a thread ... red insulation under screw ... be a perfectionist with these terminations!

Comment: The receptacle looks right assuming the wiring is what you'd expect, one possibility - if there's ONE receptacle on the circuit with the tab still on between the hots, they will ALL stay on when the switch is off.

Comment: @batsplatsterson I believe I only broke the tab on the receptacle that was to be controlled by the switch. So are you saying any receptacle fed by the red wire has to have a broken tab? I cant currently say for sure whether or not there are more than just the one that I worked on with a red wire, but it's worth a look for sure

Comment: Usually when I see this the whole room has the split receptacles, again assuming is dangerous, but I'd assume if there's a red wire on the other receptacles they were probably also split...

Comment: @batsplatsterson In my house only the outlet right under the switch was split/switched, though obviously every house (and every room) may vary. But logically if they were all split then there would be an extra red at the outlet to chain to the next one, but there isn't an extra red, only an extra black.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think your problem is the switch, but another outlet in your room. Check all of the outlets.

- Any of the outlets that you DON'T want to be switched or half-switched MUST NOT have the red wires to attached to the outlet.
- Only switched outlets should be connected to the red wire and their tab should be broken.

[image]

Comment: That's what I was thinking...

Comment: That makes perfect sense since it seems to me like the switch and outlet are wired properly. If I understand correctly. if I come across another outlet with a red wire, my options are to either hook it up and break the tab to make it controlled by the switch, or ensure that it is properly pig tailed into the red wire going out?

Comment: Yes, you are correct.

Comment: You really need to go back and look at your old receptacles and see where the tabs were broken there.  Yes, you probably have more than one switched outlet in the room, and the other one didn't have its tab broken off, as a result the tab is shorting out the switch and leaving the lamps always on.

Comment: After going through all other outlets in the room, I did find one that had a red wire feeding into it and the tab wasn’t broken so hopefully that’s the issue. Before moving forward though I did have a question. This one has two red and one black feeding the hot side. I’m assuming the reds should just have one on the screw and one in the insert and then have the tab broken?

Comment: Got it!!! That extra broken tab solved weeks of frustrations. Thank you all so much!!

Comment: Please make sure to mark this as the correct answer.